# Count identical elements near each other in matrix

Tags: matlab

Consider a matrix like

```
A =  0     1     0     1          
     1     1     0     0          
     0     0     0     0          
     1     1     1     1
```

I would like to calculate the average size of each cluster of 1's. I define a cluster as occurring when two or more 1's are near each other, i.e. next to or above/below. Eg, in this matrix there is a cluster of size 3 in the top left hand corner and a cluster of size 4 in the bottom row.

I need a way to extract this information in a non-visual way because I need to do this many times for different A.

Comment: What about diagonally adjacent?Does it count or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use [`bwlabel`](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) which isolates the connected components (*clusters of 1*) in your binary matrix.

```
A =  [0     1     0     1          
      1     1     0     0          
      0     0     0     0          
      1     1     1     1 ];

[L,n] = bwlabel(A,8)  % # for a 8-pixel stencil 
                    % # (i.e. hor/vert/diag first neighbors)
```

or

```
[L,n] = bwlabel(A,4)  % # for 4-pixel stencil 
                      % # (just horizontal & vertical neighbors)


 L =  0     1     0     3
      1     1     0     0
      0     0     0     0
      2     2     2     2
```

Doing so, you obtain a matrix `L` which *labels* the `n` different connected components.

Then you may want to extract some statistics; for instance you may want to histogram the size of the clusters.

```
   cluster_size =  hist(L(:),0:n);
   cluster_size = cluster_size(2:end);  % # histogram of component vs. size 
                                        % # (without zeros)    

   hist(cluster_size)                   % # histogram of sizes
```

[image]

which tells you thay you have one cluser of 1 element, one cluster of 3 and one cluster of four.

Finally, if you are looking for the average size of the clusters, you can do

```
mean(cluster_size)

     2.6667
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It works in this instance but it seems to breakdown when the size of the matrix is increased. Would you know why?

Comment: @user2209979, is the matrix just composed of ones or zeroes? i.e. is it binary?

Comment: It is binary. See below:
`p = 0.7
A = [zeros(10-(p*10),10);ones(p*10,10)]; % empty network
A = reshape(A,100,1);
A = A(randperm(100));
A = reshape(A,10,10);

[L,n] = bwlabel(A);
cluster_size = zeros(1,n);
   for i = 1:n
       cluster_ = L == i;
       cluster_size(i) = sum(cluster_(:));     
   end

hist(cluster_size)
mean(cluster_size)`

Comment: @user2209979, consider the updated answer. (no more for loop and 4 or 8 pixel stencil). Look at the matrix L to see if the connected components are ok with you. I guess that the high p generates large clusters. Try with lower p.

Comment: @user2209979, you may want a finer grain histogram: `hist(cluster_size,100)`